# PDF.js zooming feature implementation

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

there's a feature of pdf.js viewer that when you zoom in/out, the pdf's canvas will first be scaled up/down by css than the page will re-draw.

I want to implement this feature on my own pdf viewer, there are my steps:

1. when user zooms, scale up/down the canvas by css from the center (the step is 0.25)
2. when finishing zooming, re-draw the pdf with the scale number
3. reset css scaling to 1

my problem is, the size of new pdf doesn't match the size when we were zooming, that means user can see the pdf suddently grow/shirnk a little bit, that's werid because the scale factor is the same with zoom factor. I just can't get that where I am wrong :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.